# SQL Server stored procedure default value behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server. I want to set default value when null is passed; otherwise, use the passed value. However, I am not sure if my code reflects the behavior I want. If not, what should I do?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    (@PassedTableName nvarchar(100)) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableName AS NVarchar(255) = 'defaultTablenName'

    SELECT @TableName = QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @PassedTableName 

    DECLARE @sql0 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql0 = 'select count(*) from ' + @TableName 
    EXEC(@SQL0)
```

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to do here.

Comment: select @TableName = isnull(QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME ), 'defaultTablenName')

Comment: Are you trying to set optional parameters or just send a NULL to the parameter?

Comment: @YogeshSharma, that's my first idea too, but will it work if the select returns no row at all?

Comment: Just change @end WHERE TABLE_NAME = ISNULL(@PassedTableName, TableName)

Comment: your code should work.. did you test it to see if it reflects the behavior you want?

Comment: your edit is very confusing. What are you trying to do ? You are using the vairable TableName only for the second query, not for the first. The first query will always use what the user entered, the second will always use 'defaultTablenName'. Is that the idea ? and why ? what is your goal ?

Answer (score 3):

Just specify the default value when the parameter is declared:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    (@PassedTableName nvarchar(100) = 'defaultTableName')
```

If the user passes in a parameter, it will use it. If they exclude the parameter, it will default to `defaultTableName`.

One warning, though. If the user *includes* the parameter but explicitly specifies `NULL` (by calling `dbo.test @PassedTableName = NULL`), the value will be `NULL`. In that case, I'd recommend:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    (@PassedTableName nvarchar(100) = NULL) 

IF @PassedTableName IS NULL 
SET @PassedTableName = 'defaultTableName'
```

Comment: should the declaration not use 'defaultTableName' in stead of null ?

Comment: @GuidoG sounds right, the original example was a little vague.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `COALESCE` or by specifiying the default value when the parameter is declared.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    (@PassedTableName nvarchar(100) = 'defaultTableName')
```

or

```
DO STUFF WHERE tablename = COALESCE(@PassedTableName,'defaultTableName')
```

Either will work. There's another way by using `IF`

```
IF @PassedTableName IS NULL
  SET @PassedTableName = 'defaultTableName';
```